# variable of type 'const char *' cannot be assigned to entity of type 'char'

Tags: c, arrays, string, variables, pointers

The program is as follows

```
typedef struct Signal {
  long int vr[4];
  char name[4];
  char Type;
  char casuality[2];
};
```

and I wanted to use this structure in such way where for eg: for variable `vr` I am able to do `vr[0]=1073741824`  but for `casuality` if I assign `casuality[0]="output"` it is showing error as given above

```
 void xmlRead()
 {
    struct FMU *fmu;
    struct Signal *var;
    struct Signal iname;
    (*var).vr[0]=1073741824;
    (*var).vr[1]=1073741825;
    (*var).vr[2]=1073741826;
    (*var).vr[3]=1073741827;
    (iname).name[0]="Ball1_pos";   //Here it is showing the error//
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: your error messge was missing a `*` .. those stars are important. I've edited it in

Comment: Were you planning on actually allocating storage for `*var` before dereferencing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `"output"` is a *string literal*, having type `char [7]` and `casuality[0]` is of type `char`.

Obviously, they are not compatible (one is an array, the other a simple `char`) and hence the error.

There are two ways to *achieve* what you want,

1. Change `char casuality[2];` to `char *casuality[2];` then the assignment will work fine (however, you can't modify a *string literal*).
2. Allocate an array *long enough* and use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to *copy* the content of the string literal into the array.

Comment: Since here i am using the structures what might be the possible solution

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a string literal (made of several `char`s), to the first location of an array of four chars (`Signal.name[0]`).

```
// a single char = a string literal, i.e., from const char* to char
(iname).name[0] = "Ball1_pos";
```

This is obviously incompatible in types.

Note that even if the string literal was short enough to be fit into the memory spanned by the variable `name`, you would need a function such as [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) or [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) to assign the value to that memory.

In particular, something like the following would work:

```
strcpy(iname.name, "abc")
```

(note that string literals are null terminated by the compiler and `strcpy` includes the `\0`)

To make things (hopefully) more clear for you, the following would be equivalent:

```
iname.name[0] = 'a'
iname.name[1] = 'b'
iname.name[2] = 'c'
iname.name[3] = '\0'
```